# How to structure a database schema to allow for the "1 in a million" case?

Tags: mysql, database-design, doctrine-orm

Among all the tables in my database, I have two which currently have a `Many-to-Many` join. However, the actual data population being captured *nearly always* has a `One-to-Many` association.

Considering that I want database look-ups (doctrine queries) to be as unencumbered as possible, should I instead:

- Create two associations between the tables (where the second is only
  populated in these exceptional cases)?
- Change the datatype for the association (eg to a `text`/`tinyblob`) to record a mini array of the 2 (or technically even 3) associated records?

This is what I currently have (although TableB-> JoinTable is usually just one-to-one):

```
TableA.id --< a_id.JoinTable.b_id >-- TableB.id
```

So, I am looking to see if I can capture the 'exceptions'. Is the below the correct way to go about it?

```
TableA.id     TableB.id
       +----< TableB.A_id1
       +----- TableB.A_id2
       +----- TableB.A_id3
```

Comment: What problem is caused by modelling this as a many-to-many?

Comment: Between `many-to-many` and `one-to-one`, there is `one-to-many`. Is your `1 in a million case` really is a `many-to-many` or really a `one-to-many` relation? Modelling `one-to-many` is the same as modelling `one-to-one`.

Comment: How many can the "many" of the "1 in a million" be? Is there an iron-clad hard limit?

Comment: Thanks @DavidAldridge @Solarflare  - I meant to say `one-to-many`(!). I've updated the question

Comment: @Bohemian - there is no iron-clad limit but I can not conceive of a scenario with more than 4 associated records

Comment: "I want database look-ups (doctrine queries) to be as unencumbered as possible" But what pattern of what queries do you mean? What does "unencumbered " mean? By complicated implementation and/or queries?  By slow speed? Do you mean, you'd like to benefit from faster queries from splitting them into queries on a large 1:many table plus a small many:many table? What is your *requirement* re only n in a million records being many:many?

Comment: Is there actually a measured performance problem? If not, do nothing. If so, how much of the performance problem is attributed to this relationship and not indexing or query style etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be interested in:

```
-- a and b are related by the association of interest
Foo(a, b)

-- foo(a, b) but not foo(a2, b) for some a2 <> a
Boring(a, b)
unique(b)
FK (a, b) references Foo

-- foo(a, b) and foo(a2, b) for some a2 <> a
Rare(a, b)
FK (a, b) references foo
```

If you want *queries* to be unencumbered, just define Foo. You can query it for Rare.

```
Rare = select * from Foo f join Foo f2
    where f.a <> f2.a and f.b = f2.b
```

Any other design suffers from update complexity in keeping the database consistent.

You have some fuzzy concern about Rare being much smaller than Foo. But what is your *requirement* re only n in a million Foo records being many:many by which you would choose some other design?

The next level of complexity is to have Foo and Rare. Updates have to keep the above equation true.

It seems extremely unlikely that there is a benefit in reducing the 2-or-3-in-a-million redundancy of Foo + Rare by only having Boring + Rare and reconstructing Foo from them. But it may be of benefit to define a unique index (b) for Boring which will maintain that a b in it has only one a. When you need Foo:

```
Foo = select * from Boring union select * from Rare
```

But your updates must maintain that

```
not exists (select * from Boring b join Rare r where b.b = r.b)
```

Comment: Thank you - from your answer and the above comments to my question, it is clear I've misunderstood. My main entity is a composite of `one-to-many` and `many-to-many` associations with lots of other tables already. My thinking was that `many-to-many` associations are an added processing burden for doctrine queries when pulling symfony entities. Is this not the case? If not, then I will more than happily keep it as a `many-to-many` join-table - thanks to all for your education!

Comment: Can you be more concrete/clear about "My main entity is a composite of one-to-many and many-to-many associations with lots of other tables already."? As long as the DBMS knows that a (candidate/primary key) set of columns is unique it can index it for fast access. There's no need for that set to be limited to one column. Even when a single column is unique it should be indexed if used as a key or FK. You mention symfony and tag with doctrine & mysql. Learn about the SQL version of your collection of entities and associations. (Also normalization.)

Answer (score 1):

> Change the datatype for the association (eg to a text/tinyblob) ?

Please don't do that. If you do the people maintaining your database will curse your name unto the thousandth generation. No joke.

Your best bet here is to rig a one-to-many association. Let's say your table `a` has an integer primary key `a_id`.

Then, put that `a_id` as a foreign key column in your second table `b`.

You can retrieve your information as follows. This will always give you one row in your result set for each row in `a`.

```
 SELECT a.this, a.that, GROUP_CONCAT(b.value) value
   FROM a
   LEFT JOIN b ON a.a_id = b.a_id
  GROUP BY a.this, a.that
```

If you don't mind the extra row for your one-in-a-million case it's even easier.

```
 SELECT a.this, a.that, b.value
   FROM a
   LEFT JOIN b ON a.a_id = b.a_id
```

The `LEFT JOIN` operation allows for the case where your `a` row has no corresponding `b` row.

Put an index on `b.a_id`.